# Trace subprocesses and threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, trace, multiprocess

I have a Python script running in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) that creates processes using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library, assigning to them functions to be executed. The problem is that one of these functions gets stuck, and I want to know where it happens. I tried using `python -m trace -l myscript.py`, but it cannot show the functions that are executed in the subprocesses. Although the script below is not the one I am using, this situation also occurs when trying to trace its functions.

```
import multiprocessing

def print_hello():
    print('hello world')

def print_hello_inside_trace():
    print('trace: hello world')

def trace_function():
    print_hello_inside_trace()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hello()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=trace_function)
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

So, my question is: is there any way to trace the code executing inside Python subprocesses? Also, as curiosity, is it possible to trace Python threads?

Comment: I've no experience with subprocesses, but you can debug threads in a decent debugger. Check out e.g. Visual Studio Code.

Comment: windows or linux ?

Comment: Try adding `@snoop(depth=10)` to `trace_function` - see https://github.com/alexmojaki/snoop

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to trace `subprocess`, `multiprocessing` and `threading` module.

Use [viztracer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/viztracer).

```
pip install viztracer
viztracer --log_multiprocess your_script.py
```

And it will generate a result.html file, open it in your browser. You'll have something like this:

[image: report of viztracer]

As you can see, because viztracer trace "everything", you'll have a little bit more than you need. You need to locate the function that is of interest, and you can zoom in there to see what's happening.

[image]

There you can see the relations between your functions. When and how they called each other. If you select the function, you can also see the source code of it on the right bottom corner(maybe you can tell from the first image).

viztracer supports `multiprocessing` with `--log_multiprocess`, `subprocess` with `--log_subprocess` and `threading` module just natively.

Answer (score 2):

I would put more logging. gdb is your friend. You have to install python debugging extensions e.g. py-bt to give you python code stack trace. Regular bt will give you the c stack trace. Very good detailed explanation here [DebuggingWithGdb](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)

Run it under gdb or if its already running than attach gdb to it using pid and check the threads state using info threads.

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame
  37   Thread 0xa29feb40 (LWP 17914) "NotificationThr" 0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  36   Thread 0xa03fcb40 (LWP 17913) "python2.7" 0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  35   Thread 0xa0bfdb40 (LWP 17911) "QProcessManager" 0xb7fdd424
```

It will tell you where exactly each thread is at current state. Once you post some more details we can help.

Comment: For "if its already running than attach gdb to it using pid", my python code creates many processes how can I figure out which one should I attach gdb to ?