# multiprocessing.Pool takes varying amounts of time to set up

Tags: python, multiprocessing

As part of a longer program, I repeatedly create `multiprocessing.Pool`s to run simultaneous simulations. There is something strange going on when starting the processes where sometimes the functions would be called practically immediately, but sometimes also with a delay of 15 minutes or more where the CPUs of the computer are all idle. Given that the section is part of a larger piece of software, I am unable to create a minimal running example, but the code is structured roughly as follows:

```
args = [list comprehension constructor]
counter = 0
start_process = datetime.datetime.now()
with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 3) as pool: # The server has 32 cores
    logging.debug(f'Time to set up pool: {datetime.datetime.now() - start_process}')
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(worker_fun, args):
        if counter == 0:
            logging.debug(f'First result after: {datetime.datetime.now() - start_process}')
        counter += 1

def worker_fun(arg):
    print(f'Starting at {datetime.datetime.now()}')
    Some function
```

Both the first line in `worker_fun` as well the line `First result after: ...` usually get printed practically immediately, but sometimes all CPU cores are idle for an unknowable period of time before the printing to console starts again after which no delays are noticeable for that iteration.

Does anybody have any idea what could be happening? Python version is 3.8.10. Thanks!

Edit: I am running this in a PyCharm Debugging Console

Comment: And if it helps: The long waiting times tend to become more frequent the longer the script is running, at least in my perception.

Comment: Which operating system, and which backend? (`spawn`? `fork`? `forkserver`?)

Comment: ...in general, `spawn` makes you pay all the cost to start up a whole new copy of your Python program, so if it does anything slow while the modules are being imported, well, there's your problem. If you care about startup time and you're on an operating system that supports it (read: not on Windows), you should be using `fork` or `forkserver`.

Comment: If you _are_ on Windows and have no choice but to use `spawn`, make sure anything expensive is moved from module scope / top level into a function, and that you use `if __name__ == '__main__'` to guard those functions.

Comment: You can try adding a `pool.join()` statement following the `with multiprocessing.Pool(...) as pool:` block to ensure that all the pool processes have terminated before re-creating the pool. Otherwise you might be trying to create a new pool while other pool processes are still running.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and have not changed the default meaning that I should be forking. There are also no unusual imports, only standard libraries. The strange part is that it mostly takes no time at all, but only sometimes very long...

Comment: And the size of `args` is a few mb only and should therefore not have any impact on performance.

Comment: I'd be reaching for sysdig, ebpftrace, or another low-overhead full-system tracing tool at this point.

Comment: ...alternately, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566334/trace-subprocesses-and-threads-in-python suggests viztracer; save you the trouble from working backwards from syscalls to figure out what the interpreter's doing.

Comment: Running it outside of the debugger mode actually removes the problem (at least so far). Unfortunately, viztracer drops out for that reason since I cannot trace all of PyCharm... I will check whether I can find any more details and will report if anything useful comes up!